# How to extract first group of integers from a string?

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract the numbers beside # from the string : ackCount.
I am using indexing, but the number of digits beside hash may increase to 5 or 6..so on.
Can I get only the number immediately after the # (Not 1 that is at the last of the string)
Below is the temporary code for getting 4 digits

```
ackCount = "Acknowledgement of  #2352 on component \"lOrA-1\""
OAC = int(re.sub("\\D", "", ackCount)[0:4])
print(OAC)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
re.search(r"#(\d+)", ackCount).group(1)
```

This will search the `ackCount` string for the first occurrence of a an octothorpe ('#') followed by one or more (`+`) digits (`\d`), capturing only the digit(s) in the capture group (`.group(1)`) of the `Match` object returned by `re.search()`.

In the context of your question, this would become:

```
ackCount = "Acknowledgement of  #2352 on component \"lOrA-1\""
try:
    OAC = int(re.search(r"#(\d+)", ackCount).group(1))
    print(OAC)
# error handling if the cast to `int` fails, or there is no returned match
except ValueError, AttributeError:
    print("No match found.")
```

```
>>> 2352
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string is always the same you can use `ackCount = ackCount.split()`

This will return you a list where each element is a word in your original string. By default `split()` uses blank spaces as the delimiter.

Then get all the digits with `ackCount[2][1:]`, again assuming it is the same general string but just the digits are different. So index 2 of your list, and then all characters of the string beginning at index 1 (because index 0 of the string is '#').

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for this purpose. Make sure you make the right pattern! The following will return a list of all matches:

```
import re
string = "he hallo #9090 8080 fdsf sfd222 f222"
find = re.findall("(?<=#)[0-9]+\\b", string)
print(find)
```

Output: `['9090']`

The string `string = "he hallo #9090 8080 fdsf sfd222 f222 #888"` will return `['9090', '888']` etc.

Comment: Using a non-capturing group as a filter rather than using a capture group as intended seems like an anti-pattern. There is no benefit here to not simply capturing what you want.

Comment: I would disagree. The thing that one would want to capture is the digits **behind** the '#'. You can work around this by using the 'group()' method introduced in python 3.5, but that doesn't make the other way around an anti-pattern.